# Purchased Quantity - what is it?

Tags: cartthrob

I am trying to set up a coupon code but I don't think I understand what purchased quantity is.

I have 6 products and want to set a code that will give a 20% discount on one of these products if one of the 6 is purchased at full price.

I am assuming in this scenario I would need to use the buy x get y plugin and that:

```
buy_x_entry_ids = 1,2,3,4,5,6
Purchased Quantity = 2
get_y_entry_ids = 1,2,3,4,5,6
Discount Quantity = 1
Percentage Off = 20
Per Item Limit = 1
```

If I put 1 x product_1 and 1 x product_2 in my cart no discount is applied.

If I put 2 x product_1 and 1 x product_2 in my cart 20% discount is applied to one product.

However if I put 1 x product_1 and 2 x product_2 in my cart no discount is applied.

If I remove Purchased Quantity it is better but then applies the 20% discount on a single product in the checkout.

Any ideas what the correct settings should be?

Answer (score 1):

For your scenario you should be using the buy x of a,b,c get discount plugin. https://github.com/CartThrob/cartthrob-discounts-buy_x_of_abc

Your settings would look like this:

```
Purchased Quantity = 1
Discount Quantity = 1
Percentage Off = 20
Qualifying entry_ids = 1,2,3,4,5,6
Per Item Limit = 1
```